# ZF1 foreach correto na view

Tags: php, zend

Tenho seguinte controller (ZF1) onde eu pego o ID de todo mundo de uma tabela e com esse ID eu uso para "filtrar" e pegar dados especificos de outra tabela é um relacionamento por ID digamos assim.

```
$tabFerias = new Srh_Model_Ferias("srh");
$agendados = $tabFerias->getAll();

foreach ($agendados as $servidor)
{
    $this->id = $servidor->srh_periodo_aquisitivo_sca_pessoa_idPessoa;

    $tabPessoa = new Sca_Model_Pessoa("sca");
    $this->view->pegaId = $tabPessoa->getPessoa($this->id);

}
```

Se eu crio um outro foreach ai dentro do controller ele traz os dados correto conforme eu quero.

```
foreach ($pegaId as $agendado)
{
    $this->matricula = $agendado->matricula;
    $this->nome = $agendado->nome;
}
```

Mas quero mandar esse foreach para a view então eu faço o seguinte na mesma:

```
  <?php foreach ($this->pegaId as $agendado) : ?> 

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $agendado->matricula; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $agendado->nome; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Porém só vem informações de um usuário. Como faço para mudar isso?

functions do model:

```
public function getAll()
    {
        $resultado = $this->fetchAll();
        return $resultado;
    }   

public function getFerias($id)  
    {   
        $resultado = $this->find($id);
        return $resultado;
    }
```

Att.

Comment: Me parece que você está gravando os dados mais de uma vez na mesma propriedade. Deve vir sempre o último resultado né?

Comment: A sintaxe no echo da view está bem errada

Comment: Desculpa, não entendi. =\

Answer (score 1):

Muda seu foreach e usa um array auxiliar:

```
$pegaId = array();
foreach ($agendados as $servidor)
{
    $this->id = $servidor->srh_periodo_aquisitivo_sca_pessoa_idPessoa;

    $tabPessoa = new Sca_Model_Pessoa("sca");
    $pegaId[] = $tabPessoa->getPessoa($this->id);

}
$this->view->pegaId = $pegaId;
```